# Hyperledger fabric "make all" error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum

Step 15 : LABEL org.hyperledger.fabric.version 1.1.0-snapshot-f8e65f50 org.hyperledger.fabric.base.version 0.4.1
 ---> Running in 54618f9e5e8d
 ---> d3873ab264ac
Removing intermediate container 54618f9e5e8d
Successfully built d3873ab264ac
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-javaenv hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64-1.1.0-snapshot-f8e65f50
build/bin/peer
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/home/demoUser/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -tags "experimental" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=1.1.0-snapshot-f8e65f50 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseVersion=0.4.1 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.DockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerNamespace=hyperledger -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Experimental=true" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
import cycle not allowed
package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    imports fmt
    imports errors
    imports runtime
    imports runtime/internal/atomic
    imports runtime
Makefile:233: recipe for target 'build/bin/peer' failed
make: *** [build/bin/peer] Error 1

We are getting above error while doing "make all" for hyperledger fabric. We tried with "make clean" then "make all" but every time gets the same error, Any solution/remedy for above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue related to go version 1.4, We have upgrade go to 1.9 and "make all" done properly.